# Spell out the time

Tags: java, c++, python, linux, perl

Are there any libraries or utilities that will formally spell out the time?

```
Examples:   
5:37 -> five thirty-seven   
2:00 -> two o'clock   
4:05 -> five past four   
12:00 -> noon
```

Bonus if it can also spell out the date.

Comment: Have you looked at [Pretty Time](http://ocpsoft.org/prettytime/) ?

Comment: @sarnold I think for this kind of question, "where have you looked" is better than "what have you tried." If the OP had tried solving the problem on their own, the responses would be "don't reinvent the wheel! Find a library that already does that for you."

Comment: @octern: perhaps -- it just seems like such a simple task that looking for a tool would take longer than just writing one. (Of course, a library might already have localizations to hundreds of locales..)

Comment: Gosh, it wouldn't be hard to write this yourself.

Comment: You could buy this nifty clock!  http://www.qlocktwo.com/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Several. Perl options include [Time::Human](http://p3rl.org/Time%3a%3aHuman) (and the related [DateTime::Format::Human](http://p3rl.org/DateTime%3a%3aFormat%3a%3aHuman)), [Time::Fuzzy](http://p3rl.org/Time%3a%3aFuzzy), and [Time::ProseClock](http://p3rl.org/Time%3a%3aProseClock).

Comment: Thanks this is what I was looking for. I am afraid that google failed me this time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use http://babel.edgewall.org/wiki/Documentation/dates.html#time-delta-formatting for formatting time strings and then use http://wiki.python.org/moin/Audio for audio.